# Files list file for package 'qdbus' is missing final newline (Raspbian)

Tags: apt, raspbian, dpkg

I have a fresh install of Raspbian on a raspberry pi 3. It boots fine, and I am able to perform any function that I can think of with one exception: any attempt to install or remove a package results in the error "Files list file for package 'qdbus' is missing final newline". Indeed the file at /var/lib/dpkg/info/qdbus.list is full of garbage.

What I tried so far:

- Adding a newline to the file.
- $sudo apt-get clean  -  did nothing.
- Delete qdbus.list  -  a different file is indicated as corrupted, I got as far as deleting about 25 files before things like ssh stopped working and I had to re-install the OS.
- Reinstall the OS from a fresh, hash-checked download of the latest version
- $sudo dpkg --configure -a  -  did nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of apt-get upgrade]
[image: Screenshot of vi /var/lib/dpkg/info/qdbus.list]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered same problem. And I solved this by downgrading raspbian jessie.

http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/raspbian-2017-06-23/

Remove your current version probably `raspbian-2017-07-05/` and downgrade to `raspbian-2017-06-23/`. It will require a lot more time to update and upgrade packages but works fine for me.

Comment: That did fix the problem, thank you. I wonder if everyone is having an issue with this version of Jessie.

Comment: We had this same issue with this exact build. The 07-05 image must just be corrupt. We checked that the SHA256 checksum matches and tried applying the image twice.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, but found another solution. It is caused whilst writing the Jessie image to the SD Card, not sure why this has changed between 06-23 and 07-05 builds. If you are using OSX then include conv=sync option for dd

sudo dd if=/path/to/Downloads/2017-07-05-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m conv=sync

also discussed in https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=187936

This fixed the problem for me.